# lineWidth for UIBezierPath has maximum

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create an arc, like a half circle, that i can animate with different colors.  I thought I would start with creating a bezier path for the arc and setting the line width to something large. This is what I have so far:

```
CAShapeLayer *layer = (CAShapeLayer *)self.layer;
UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y + self.bounds.size.height / 2);
[bezierPath moveToPoint:startPoint];
layer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
layer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
CGFloat strokeSize = 10;

CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(self.bounds.origin.x + self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.origin.y + self.bounds.size.height / 2);

[bezierPath setLineWidth:100];
[bezierPath addQuadCurveToPoint:endPoint controlPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.origin.x + self.bounds.size.width / 2, self.bounds.origin.y)];
bezierPath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
layer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
```

When I see my arc though, it doesn't look any bigger than a thin path.  Is this the way to create something like that?  Or do I need to create two paths and somehow fill the area between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the layer's lineWidth, not the bezier path's,

```
layer.lineWidth = 100;
```