# Why does my 3D extruded UIBezierPath have duplicates?

Tags: swift, scenekit, uibezierpath

I have a series of `UIBezierPath`'s that I've turned into 3D objects in SceneKit. They form a long, jagged line with occasional gaps (a gap separates one object from another).

Here's what that looks like:
[image]

**The problem:** As I move the camera around, the material on the side of the objects flickers strangely and changes colors.

I believe what's happening is that my path-drawing code is wrong, and is somehow creating duplicate objects positioned *inside* the existing object(s). So, I think the flickering color is really the other, duplicate object showing through.

Here's what the flickering color showing through looks like:
[image]

To see the problem in action, the following code can be pasted directly into a new `Game` template Xcode project using `SceneKit`. You may paste it at the end of `GameViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`.

```
var previousBezierPathPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
let numOfPointsPerLine: Int = 8
var hugePath = UIBezierPath()
var wasGap: Bool = false
let gapWidth: CGFloat = 10.0
var currentZdepth: CGFloat = CGFloat.random(in: 5.0...30.0)
for i in 0..<14 {
   let pp = wasGap ? CGPoint(x: CGFloat(previousBezierPathPoint.x) + gapWidth, y: CGFloat(previousBezierPathPoint.y)) : CGPoint(x: CGFloat(previousBezierPathPoint.x), y: CGFloat(previousBezierPathPoint.y))
   let isGap: Bool = i > 1 && Float.random(in: 0...100) > 60.0
            
   if !isGap {
      if wasGap || i == 0 {
         hugePath = UIBezierPath()

         hugePath.move(to: pp)
                    
         currentZdepth = CGFloat.random(in: 5.0...30.0)
      }
                
      for j in 1..<numOfPointsPerLine {
          let point = CGPoint(x: pp.x + (CGFloat(j)*25.0), y: pp.y + CGFloat.random(in: -8.0...8.0))
                    
          hugePath.addLine(to: point)
                    
          previousBezierPathPoint = point
      }
                
      let pathRef = hugePath.cgPath.copy(strokingWithWidth: 10.0, lineCap: CGLineCap.butt, lineJoin: CGLineJoin.miter, miterLimit: 1.0)
      let newPath = UIBezierPath(cgPath: pathRef.normalized())
                
      let hugeShape = SCNShape(path: newPath, extrusionDepth: currentZdepth)

      let colors = [
                    UIColor.green,
                    UIColor.yellow,
                    UIColor.purple,
                    UIColor.gray,
                    UIColor.darkGray
      ]
      let tempMat = SCNMaterial()
      tempMat.diffuse.contents = colors[Int.random(in: 0..<colors.count)]
      let frontMat = SCNMaterial()
      frontMat.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
      hugeShape.materials = [frontMat, tempMat, tempMat, tempMat, tempMat, tempMat]

      let hugeNode = SCNNode()
      hugeNode.geometry = hugeShape

      hugeNode.position.x = 0.0
      hugeNode.position.z = Float(-50.0 + (currentZdepth*0.5))
      hugeNode.position.y = 0.0

      scnView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(hugeNode)
      } else {
         if hugePath.isEmpty == false {
            hugePath.close()
         }
      }
            
      wasGap = isGap
}
```

Please note that this question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75138465/set-linewidth-of-uibezierpath-for-use-in-scenekit/75152950?).

**Question:** How can I change my code so that there are no duplicate objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are continually building your path each time through the loop...

Not entirely sure if this will give you your desired results, but...

Instead of this:

```
    if wasGap || i == 0 {
        hugePath = UIBezierPath()
                
        hugePath.move(to: pp)
                
        currentZdepth = CGFloat.random(in: 5.0...30.0)
    }
```

try this:

```
    hugePath = UIBezierPath()
    hugePath.move(to: pp)

    if wasGap || i == 0 {
        currentZdepth = CGFloat.random(in: 5.0...30.0)
    }
```

Comment: In the end, I removed the `if wasGap || i == 0` condition entirely, and that solved the problem (or mostly solved it). Thank you!

Comment: @West1 - by the way... I don't know how precise you want your shapes to connect, but you can avoid the asymmetrical overlap (top) by splitting the last segment of a shape in half and using the other half as the first part of the next segment (bottom): https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKb0B.png